# get output string after access a link

Tags: go

I am writing a program by Go.
In this program, I access to a website and in this website, it will print a string. I want to get this string for next process.
For example:

I access by curl and the returned string will like that:

```
curl localhost:4000
abc_example
```

I need to get "abc_example" for next process in my program.
Now, this problem was solved.

Actually, my result will be a JSON like that:

```
{"name":"xyz_example"}
```

How can I parse this string and just get "xyz_example"

I am a newbie in Go. May you help me.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of reading the response from an HTTP request.
I would recommend reading up on the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) for the http package, and maybe a simple tutorial like [this one](https://medium.com/@masnun/making-http-requests-in-golang-dd123379efe7).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {
    //make a request
    response, err := http.Get("https://mdtf.org")
    if err != nil {
      fmt.Println("error making request: ", err)
      return
    }

    //make sure the response body gets closed
    defer response.Body.Close()

    //read the bytes
    responseBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    if err != nil {
      fmt.Println("error reading response bytes: ", err)
      return
    }

    //turn the response bytes into a string
    responseString := string(responseBytes)

    //print it or something
    fmt.Println(responseString)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Mr Opnauticus. I want to ask one more question. 
My result will be a JSON like that: 
    
    {"name":"xyz_example"}

How can I parse this string and get just "xyz_example"
Thank you

Comment: That depends what the server you are querying is serving up. What you just posted (`{"name":"xyz_example"}`) is JSON - whereas your original question was about a server that returns a string. Either way, something very much like this example is how you would get that response, but if you're expecting JSON, you would probably want to parse the `responseBytes` with the "encoding/json" package rather than just casting to a string.

Comment: Thank you so much for your keyword. I can do it now :D